# How can I use Git/GitHub to deploy a discord.js bot to a remote server (that I own and is on my network) without having to manually FTP into it

Tags: git, deployment, discord.js, production, ubuntu-server

So I develop Discord.JS bots, and host them on a server I own in my home. I generally program and test them on my personal device, but host them on a dedicated device. The problem is, in order for me to make an update, I have to manually FTP into this device to edit the files.

I use GitHub and Git for these projects, and I have a development branch and a production branch. I'm wondering if it's possible to automate the process; when I push into the production branch, it will update the files on the server for me.

Keep in mind I am still semi-new to GitHub so if it is simple I do apologize for that. Is there any software for this, or can it be done through Git? Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you consider using a cronjob that could run a pull so that the files update automagically?

Comment: @eftshift0 never used cronjob, could you explain it more?

Comment: If yours is a linux server, you might very easily set up a cronjob that took care of running a fetch and checkout the remote branch so that the site is (almost) automagically updated without invervention.

Comment: @etfshift0 -- yes it's a Linux server, do you have any tutorials/threads that would be helpful? Thank you!

Comment: I am hosting several bots on my personal server. I have set it up as a file server, so I can access my files in the explorer from any machine in the same network. 
For running bot instances I am using an NPM package called pm2. It works for me like a charm, and I dont have to FTP into my server. The most I have to do, is ssh into it to see the logs (which you could also display in Discord programically).

Comment: @ChristophBlüm I am using PM2 (which is great)! But what I was looking for was a better way of updating the files, instead of using a file server, but thank you!

(Also there is a web interface for PM2, you don't need to SSH into it to see the logs!)

Comment: @FxllenCode i know about the Webinterface but sadly, none of my logs show up there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @eftshift0 mentioned in their comment, you can use a cronjob and git clone.

To do this, you will need to edit the crontab file, use the `crontab -e` command.

At the bottom of the file, insert:

```
frequency    git clone https://<github_username>:<url_encoded_github_password>@github.com/<github_username>/<repo_name> /path/to/directory
```

`frequency` should be something like `* * * * *`. You can find what you need [here](https://crontab.guru/). It will be the interval between which updates are made.

To url encode your password, you can use [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Edit:

As @eftshift0 has mentioned, you can also create a bash file, and then run that from crontab.

The file would contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/

git clone https://<github_username>:<url_encoded_github_password>@github.com/<github_username>/<repo_name>
```

Your repo would be in /path/to/<repo_name>

In `crontab -e` you would have to append:

```sh
frequency    /bin/sh /path/to/file.sh
```

Comment: Actually, write a scrpt that can take care of all the steps to update... when you have that, call it from contab.

Comment: @eftshift0 I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Hmm... having issues here. I set it up like this, seems to not be working: `frequency */5 * * * * git clone -b production https://github.com/FxllenCode/AutoModeratorDiscordBot.git /.djsbots/AutoMod` is what I have done, but it does not update even when I push to production. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @FxllenCode Remove the word `frequency`. It was a placeholder for `*/5 * * *` or whatever interval you decide to use

Comment: Hmm... I still cannot get it to work, what am I doing wrong? Is there a way to view the logs of a cronjob?

Comment: What does the cronjob line look like?

Comment: @FxllenCode Also, try to run the command without the frequency part, if it fails, you know where the issue is. Ensure you're using the command format I supplied and let me know how it goes

Comment: @MartinNajemi this is my CronJob: `*/5 * * * * git clone -b production https://github.com/FxllenCode/AutoModeratorDiscordBot.git /.djsbots/AutoMod`. It doesn't include the word frequency.

Comment: Update: I just learned a about [CapRover](https://caprover.com/), I wonder if this would make deployment easier?

Comment: @FxllenCode Please copy the format of crontab which was supplied by me. `https://<github_username>:<url_encoded_github_password>@github.com/<github_username>/<repo_name>`. If you don't know how to follow the instructions, don't say you're having issues, say you don't understand what you need to do.

Comment: @FxllenCode Please attempt to run `git clone -b production https://github.com/FxllenCode/AutoModeratorDiscordBot.git /.djsbots/AutoMod` in the console. If it doesn't work, you know where the issue is.

Comment: If the repo is private, you will need to use the url format i provided, with the username and url encoded password.

Comment: @MartinNajemi the reason I did not follow your intructions is due to the fact I have TOTP enabled for my GitHub, so I do not know how to go about encoding it into the URI, this was confirmed by trying `sudo git clone -b production https://github.com/FxllenCode/AutoModeratorDiscordBot.git /.djsbots/AutoMod'`, as authentication still fails even if I use the correct password.

Comment: @FxllenCode You can use a personal access token.

Comment: @FxllenCode https://webkul.com/blog/github-push-with-two-factor-authentication/

Comment: @MartinNajemi Awesome, it did work the first time! The only issue I'm having is now when I run the command, it says the path already exists and is not an empty directory, does this mean in my cron job I should be purging that directory first? Thank you! :D

Comment: @FxllenCode You may need to do so, however running `git clean -i` or `git reset --hard` in the directory before pulling *should* do the trick